# Run JS file only once per session

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, session

I have got JS file with this script:
(I edited my script and added `sessionStorage` check)

```
let executed = window.sessionStorage.getItem("sessionCodeExecuted")
console.log(executed)
let uri = window.location;
let lang = window.navigator.language;
if (executed != 1) {
if( uri.href.indexOf('lang') < 0) {
if ((lang != 'ru-RU') && (lang != 'ru')){
eng = window.location.href.includes('https://www.site/en/');

if (eng == false){
let re = "https://www.site/";
let url = window.location.href;
let newstr = url.replace(re, 'https://www.site/en/');
newstr += "?currency=USD";
window.location.href = newstr;
   }
  }
 }
window.sessionStorage.setItem("sessionCodeExecuted", 1);
}
```

I want to run it only once per session. I started session with this code in functions.php:

```
  if (!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
```

console.log writes 1 but is script still running. What is wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? If you want to limit this code based on a PHP session, then store a piece of information in the session which tells if it was already run or not and use AJAX to communicate with the client.

Comment: If you want to run the code in one session in the browser, you can create a cookie for this with a value of 0. This means that the cookie will be deleted when the user ends the session in the browser. Check for the existence of this cookie

Answer (score 2):

If it's JavaScript, why not just use `sessionStorage`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API#sessionStorage

For example, something like:

```
let mySessionLang = "ru-RU";
sessionStorage['mySession'] = mySessionLang;
let readValue = sessionStorage['mySession'];
console.log(readValue);
```

Comment: I have edited my question and added sessionStorage. Can you check it one more time, please?

Comment: Does it work for you now? What would you like me to check?

Comment: No, it does not work. I wrote a script with storageSession in my question

Answer (score 1):

You could try wrapping your code in an `if` block which checks for a flag in the [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

```js
if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("sessionCodeExecuted")) {
    let uri = window.location;
    let lang = window.navigator.language;

    if (uri.href.indexOf("lang") < 0) {
        if (lang != "ru-RU" && lang != "ru") {
            eng = window.location.href.includes("https://www.site/en/");

            if (eng == false) {
                let re = "https://www.site/";
                let url = window.location.href;
                let newstr = url.replace(re, "https://www.site/en/");
                newstr += "?currency=USD";
                window.location.href = newstr;
            }
        }
    }

    window.sessionStorage.setItem("sessionCodeExecuted", true);
}
```

This snippet won't run properly because it is sandboxed, but you get the idea.

Comment: I have edited my question and added sessionStorage. Can you check it one more time, please?